# Integrating WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 BAM Analytics

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-bam

We have discovered a major issue with WSO2 API Manager 1.3 and it's integration into the WSO2 BAM 2.0.1 analytics product and I'm wondering if anyone out there has worked around this issue?

Details

After 100 calls trying to log API data to the BAM server all further calls will fail and in some cases this will stop the API Manager server from service API requests also.

The problem occurs in the DataPublisher.java class that acquires a permit from one semaphore and then releases the permit on the wrong semaphore.

Mentioned in the JIRA issue at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-992

This is obviously a blocker for us in using API Manager as we can no longer show clients any API analytics - hoping someone out there has had a similar problem and fingers crossed a work around.

Comment: An update for anyone interested - based on this acknowledged bug in WSO2 API Manager 1.3.x, we have implemented the Google Analytics method of stats collection and it works reasonably well for a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done some major improvements to API Manager's Data publisher. These fixes will be included in 1.4.0 release, which will be ready by end of April.

We are planning to push preview releases from this week on wards. I am not particularly sure if the mentioned issue is fixed by now. However We have made this a blocker for 1.4.0 release. Hence, if not fixed by now it will be taken up soon. We will be updating the JIRA issue with progress.

Comment: Thank you for the update @Sumedha, it definitely was a blocker for us and I look forward to the fix.  It will also allow the proper integration with BAM for billing and metering of API usage.